# UV-Transparent Plastic?

Tags: polymers, plastics, optical-properties

I am looking for a type of plastic, preferably in the form of a sheet or film, that is weatherproof, durable, flexible, and both transparent and UV-transparent. Most films I've seen so far are treated to be UV-resistant, where can I find untreated plastics for purchase?
Planning to use this plastic in order to cover a solar panel, without inhibiting energy output.

Comment: The number of UV photons compared to those in the visible is very small, not only because of the black-body distribution from the sun but also because atmospheric ozone absorbs a lot of UV. So it may not be a cost effective solution since PMMA sheet is expensive. (They are treated to be UV resistant to extend their lifetime against UV induced photochemistry)

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider PMMA?

A 3 mm [Plexiglas G UVT](http://www.plexiglas.com/export/sites/plexiglas/.content/medias/downloads/sheet-docs/plexiglas-g-uvt.pdf) layer seems to have a transmittance > 80% at $\lambda = 300~\mathrm{nm}$ and above.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with Klaus's [recommendation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/63913/11367), PMMA is likely your best bet.

The UV disposable cuvettes we buy here are from BrandTech; below is a UV transmission chart for various materials from one of their [marketing brochures](https://www.brandtech.com/wp-content/uploads/cuvettegraph.pdf) (click image to enlarge):

[image: cuvette plastic transmittance curves]

They've clearly had success in developing materials with even better UV transmittance (green and yellow curves) than PMMA (red curve), but it looks like the latter may be your best option.